# How do you add a Django form to a wagtail block

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to add a form to a wagtail block. The form is a simple drop down selection with a submit button.

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    example = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Example.objects.all())
```

Then the wagtail block is a simple table that is generated with get_context()

```
# this is basically the view rendering
def get_context(self, request, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context(request, **kwargs)
    # do some queries and populate tables in template.
    context['example_data'] = SomeObject.objects.all()
    # here is where I want to add the form.
    this_form = SomeForm()
    context['this_form'] = this_form
    return context
```

But how do you habdle form submissions and everything? It seems that wagtail takes away the idea of a view so I don't know if its possible to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to add a 'form that submits' within a Streamfield Block within the editing interface? Or did you want to select an existing form from Streamfield and have this present as a submittable form on the view (live page)?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to the view for practical purposes is the [`serve()` method](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.2/reference/pages/model_recipes.html?highlight=serve#overriding-the-serve-method). There you can handle `if request.method == "POST":` and so on. Perhaps:

```
def serve(self, request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyFormClass(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the form here...
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.reverse_subpage('thanks'))

    else:
        form = MyFormClass()

    context = self.get_context(request)
    context['form'] = form
    return render(
        request,
        self.get_template(request),
        context
    )
```

Alternatively, for a page type that records simple form submissions and provides a UI for editors to amend the forms, Wagtail already has the [Form builder](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.2/reference/contrib/forms/index.html) contrib module. The code above is largely [taken from there](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailforms/models.py#L238).

Also possibly relevant is [`RoutablePageMixin`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.2/reference/contrib/routablepage.html#module-wagtail.contrib.wagtailroutablepage), which allows you to have multiple 'views' for a page model, at different URLs. I've used this in the code above with the redirection to the 'thanks' subpage.

Comment: I've just noticed that you wanted to add it to a 'block', so I guess you're talking about Streamfield blocks. This rules out using Form builder.